# How to get a handle on default MousePosition elements in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

I have an OpenLayers interface with two maps side-by-side.  They are synced so that any pan or zoom action on either map affects both of them.

I also have MousePosition controls on each map so that the user can see the lon/lat coords on mouseover.  I like having a separate MousePosition on each map rather than a single one in an external div.  I was able to sync the MousePosition controls to one another using the code below.

My question is this:  Is there a better way to get a handle on the MousePosition elements?  The getElement approach I'm using feels a bit hacky.  Thanks.

```
map1.events.register("mousemove", map1, function (e) {
  var position = map1.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(e.xy).transform(WGS84_SM, WGS84);
  var lat = position.lat.toFixed(5);
  var lon = position.lon.toFixed(5);
OpenLayers.Util.getElement("OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition_68").innerHTML =
                           "<label>" + lon + " " + lat + "</label>";
});

map2.events.register("mousemove", map2, function (e) {
  var position = map2.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(e.xy).transform(WGS84_SM, WGS84);
  var lat = position.lat.toFixed(5);
  var lon = position.lon.toFixed(5);
OpenLayers.Util.getElement("OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition_37").innerHTML =
                           "<label>" + lon + " " + lat + "</label>";
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just listen to the mouse-move event and write to your own div and just place it on top of your map with relative positioning and a high z-index?  Then you'll know exactly the ID of each div and can write to it what you like.

Comment: Agreed, this seems like the best way to do it. Thanks.